# HTMLAgilityPack SelectNodes to select all <img> elements

Tags: c#, html, regex, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am making a project in C# that's basically an image screen scraper for an image-search related game. I'm trying to use HTMLAgilityPack to select all the image elements and put them in an HTMLNodeCollection, like this:

```
//set up for checking autos

HtmlNodeCollection imgs = new HtmlNodeCollection(doc.DocumentNode.ParentNode);
imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");

foreach (HtmlNode img in imgs)
{
    HtmlAttribute src = img.Attributes["@src"];
    urls.Add(src.Value);
}
```

Note that *urls* is a public List collection:

```
public List<string> urls = new List<string>();
```

My foreach loop is throwing an exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Checking the autos, sure enough, *imgs* is null. Is there any better way I can track down the source of this problem? I have no idea if it's my Xpath or what.

The most frustrating part is that I had already gotten it to work, but messed up my file versions and lost my work. Derp.

Comment: Where are you loading the `HtmlDocument`.... Are you using `Load()` or `LoadHtml()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might have a typo in the following line:

```
HtmlAttribute src = img.Attributes["@src"];
```

I got this to work for me (notice the @ position):

```
HtmlAttribute src = img.Attributes[@"src"];
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me. I think your document isn't loaded correctly, hence the xpath returns no matches.

```
HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml("<html><head></head><body><div><img /><div><img /><img/></div></div><img/></body></html>");

var nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
// 4 nodes found
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Interesting Test method. Thanks.