# Html Agility Pack selectnodes returns null

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm working on Windows Phone 8 device and try to parse html document with html agility pack from http://www.livescience.com/41480-3d-printed-kidneys-take-small-steps.html I can get the `<title>` tag easily but now I want to get the whole `<p>` tags from that document. I've tried these two solution [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883449/htmlagilitypack-selectnodes-to-select-all-img-elements) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737757/c-html-agility-selecting-every-paragraph-within-a-div-tag) but it not work. This is my actual code from based on those solutions

```
private void loadDoc()
    {
        try
        {
            HtmlWeb.LoadAsync("http://www.livescience.com/41480-3d-printed-kidneys-take-small-steps.html", Html_Completed);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void Html_Completed(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e)
    {
        doc = e.Document;
        title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title");
        p = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
        foreach(var node in p)
        {
          pr = node.InnerText; //that's the text you are looking for
        }
        text1.Text = title.InnerText;
        if (!pr.Equals("") && pr != "")
        {
            text2.Text = pr;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("null");
        }
    }
```

I use `if` block to determine whether the `foreach` returns null. Does anybody know how to solve this problem? I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
p = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//p");
```

instead of:

```
p = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
```

since `p` is a type of tag, not a class or id.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code but it probably doesn't do what you expect. The `foreach` loop iterates all paragraphs (13 in total in the case of the provided url). Because the last paragraph is empty, `pr` will be empty after the last iteration.

If you want to fill `text2` with all the paragraphs you should change the code like this:

```
pr += node.innerText;
```

If you want `pr` to contain readable text you need to decode the innerText because it can contain html entities like `&gt;`. You can do that like this:

```
pr += HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(node.innerText);
```

Hope this helps.